# Is there an indication that technology is used to eliminate extreme inequality on Earth in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, robots, government, economy, medicine

I think I have seen someone apparently vacuuming(?) aboard the Enterprise or some starship in some version of Star Trek. But it seems to me that even if advanced AI is avoided -- we only see rare androids/robots in Star Trek -- more primitive robots which farm/clean/serve in restaurants and perhaps cook could exist. But I have not seen them.

Without them, while replicators might mean everyone has food, without robots, someone is still stuck with the jobs most people don't want. Does any episode/movie/book give us an idea of how people are not forced into dangerous or unpleasant jobs or indeed, do such jobs still exist? Is free and advanced medical care available for all and is that effected by either using limited but advanced AI that can do operations?

Is anyone disabled due to inability to pay for operations? Is anyone much shorter than average or too tall or fat or ugly due to inability to get elective medical procedures? Are people within reason allowed to enhance their intelligence using technology? I believe I saw  an episode in which it is revealed that Bashir was illegally made much more intelligent than he would have been. (I think he was born subnormal? Not sure recalling correctly.)

Comment: I presume you mean "...on Earth", since the universe of Star Trek is a very big place

Comment: Wouldn't "equality" mean that everyone can work, not only the scientific and artistic geniuses, but also those with no talents beyond sweepong floors? Is inequality so bad in *Star Trek* that only the super-elite can work, and everybody else is on the dole?

Comment: Medical automation at least seems fairly primitive. It's not until *Voyager* that we're shown an automated doctor and he has, to put it mildly, some flaws as a healer. Prior to that, and even after it except in emergency situations, every time we see medical procedures they're carried out by a staff of living specialists not dissimilar from today.

Comment: I would hope that by the 24th century people would not be charged for medical care. In the UK we've had the National Health Service since about 1947 - if you're ill you go to hospital and the cost is covered.

Comment: @GordonD: My big and sad concern is this: I see with my own eyes how people who are poor are not only denied educational opportunities but even proper nutrition -- the "unseen hand" seems to try to arrange a never-ending supply of desperate people to do crummy jobs. Only AI and robotics can save us, as scared as many are of this. It is self-evident: Most people lead lives of quiet desperation. Clearly true and clearly unjust. That is what Gene's idea was for: to show us how much better things might be someday.

Comment: It would be challenging to charge people for medical procedures when there is no money. A worst case would be people needing to barter or exchange work for work, but Earth is described to be a paradise or utopia. As for food, replicators would make sustenance easily available for all, but there are still cafes, restaurants and pubs run by civilians.

Comment: Out-of-universe, Gene Roddenberry probably did believe in a connection bt. automation & a utopian future--he's quoted [here](https://arthurcclarke.org/site/how-arthur-c-clarke-helped-save-star-trek/) saying Arthur C. Clarke's 1962 *Profiles of the Future* had a big influence on Trek, and that book included a chapter on the universal "Replicator" which said things like 'A society based on the Replicator would be so completely different from ours that the present debate between Capitalism and Communism would become quite meaningless. All material possessions would be literally cheap as dirt.'

Comment: Also, in the [1967 Star Trek writer's guide](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/1_Original_Series/Star_Trek_TOS_Writer's_Guide.pdf), Roddenberry wrote on p. 16 that "References by our characters to Earth will simply a logical projection of current scientific and social advances ... But for obvious reasons, let's not get into any detail of Earth's politics of STAR TREK's century; for example, which socio-economic systems ultimately worked out best." Presumably he wouldn't have felt the need to be ambiguous if the assumption was that it was a straightforward capitalist system.

Comment: @Hypnosifl That's kind of the issue with trying to present a post-scarcity society to modern audiences. Such a society would be incompatible with any modern economic systems and becomes difficult to describe in depth because we lack the economic language to describe it.

Comment: I question the assumption that cleaning or other such jobs are necessarily jobs most people don't want, and someone is 'stuck' with them.  First of all, if it is a post-scarcity society, how would you force someone to be 'stuck' with such a job?  Second, what jobs people want or don't want, is *culturally* determined.  It is not necessarily the same as you, personally, see it.

Comment: @Basya That is true too. Some people take great satisfaction in cleaning and performing other "menial" tasks. But beyond that, there **may** be some sort of automated cleaning, at least on Star Fleet vessels. In TNG: Up the Long Ladder a comment is made by Riker that the ship cleans itself. Whether he meant that literally or he simply means that there are crewmen assigned to do so isn't clarified.

Comment: @Basya: I think it is highly unlikely that people doing jobs that i would not like someone really enjoy them. How many times has a doctor or college professor given up his position to clean motel rooms? Or to mine coal or gold in one of those illegal mining operations in Brazil?

Comment: If a person took a lot of time training to be a doctor, or a college professor, he is unlikely to give it up to clean.  That is a red herring argument.  There are some people for whom to become a doctor or a college professor, is not desirable.  Some people actually enjoy cleaning.  I would not choose that as my first choice job, but I would, for example, much prefer to work as a cleaner than to work in a job which required that I do something dishonest.  Just because cleaning is looked down on in today's Western society, does not mean it always would be (it was not, in the way I was raised.)

Comment: I don't want to get into a long conversation with someone who is obviously unconcerned for his fellow human.

Comment: That comment is uncalled for.

Comment: @Basya: You rationalize the endless cycle of poverty that keeps families stuck in menial jobs that do not pay enough for a decent, healthy and educated life. Sure, people clean up after others because they find satisfaction in it  Have you ever spoken with a housekeeper? I have. I calls 'em like I see them. My last reply to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some examples of technology used to improve or enhance people but they are generally the exception over the rule. In most cases technology is used to help people compensate for physical shortcomings, whether congenital or accidental, but not to become super human.

As you mentioned, genetic engineering does exist in the Federation but its acceptance is a mixed bag. In the pre-Federation era it is generally shunned by Humans (ENT: Cold Station 12), but by the time of The Next Generation it is accepted in laboratory environments (TNG: Unnatural Selection) but is not acceptable for regular people to use (DSN: Doctor Bashir, I Presume). However, in utero genetic manipulation is used to correct congenital issues before birth (VOY: Lineage).

As for bio-mechanical enhancements, they appear to only be used to correct or compensate for physical shortcomings. We see Geordi using a visor due to congenital blindness (TNG: The Enemy) and later upgrades to ocular implants (First Contact). Worf temporarily uses neural transducers after a spinal injury to restore movement to his legs (TNG: Ethics). And Picard had his heart replaced after being stabbed as a young officer (TNG: Tapestry). Mechanical chairs are also used for immobile individuals (TOS: The Menagerie, TNG: Too Short a Season). We even see implants being used to help people with severe brain damage (DSN: Life Line).

Regarding artificial lifeforms or other dumb mechanical beings doing grunt work, this doesn't appear to have been done prior to the failed EMH mark 1. Even when the crew of the Enterprise encounter the exocomps they view them as novel rather than something that is common place or has a similar analogue in Star Fleet (TNG: The Quality of Life). However, when Starfleet removed the EMH mk1 from sickbay they were repurposed to work on waste barges to scrub plasma conduits (VOY: Life Line). We also later see mark 1s working in dilithium mines (VOY: Author, Author). Instead of decommissioning hundreds of obsolete programs Star Fleet chose to repurpose them into menial laborers, implying that they had no preexisting artificial workforce.

Comment: It is probably a common theme in scifi: "Paradises" are not all they are cracked up to be. One of the most important ideas, perhaps THE most important idea I ever encountered is that we are made happy by improvements in our situation: someone born rich would not appreciate a weekend at the Four Seasons; a min wage worker given that same weekend would be amazed. (And maybe panic counting the minutes until it is over.) I would like to see a ST episode showing the happy citizens of Earth.